# Access an IntelliJ path variable within a gradle script

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle, repository, path-variables

Is it possible to refer to an IntelliJ path variable within a gradle script?

I have something like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url System.getenv('SOME_DIR')
    }
}
```

Where SOME_DIR is set up in IntelliJ as a Path Variable pointing to a directory on the file system that contains a maven repository.

When I have this setup, and tap the Intellij gradle sync button, I get an error saying `Error: You must specify a URL for a Maven repository`

Comment: is the value of SOME_DIR available from the command line?

Comment: @RaGe No it's not.  It's only set up as an IntelliJ path variable.